# React: Setting a dual color slider thumb to an image with transparent background

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider, styled-components

I made a slider that is supposed to be blue on the left and gray on the right. The blue is also supposed to be thicker than the gray.

[image]

I have 2 problems with it.

1. If the thumb piece has a transparent cutout, then the blue part of the slider doesn't extend all the way to the left side of what is visible on the image.
2. I would like the edges of the slider to be round, especially the blue edge(I might not need the gray)

---

By round edges I mean like this [image]

---

[Here is a codesandbox of the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-hermann-htuks?file=/src/App.js)

And the code itself

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
const image = "https://i.imgur.com/XMfYtkv.png";
const thumb = {
  width: 25,
  height: 26
};

const height = 36;
const trackHeight = 4;

// colours
const lowerBackground = `linear-gradient(to bottom, gray, gray) 100% 50% / 100% ${
  trackHeight / 2.5
}px no-repeat transparent`;
const upperBackground = `linear-gradient(to bottom, blue, blue) 100% 50% / 100% ${
  trackHeight / 2.5
}px no-repeat transparent`;

const makeLongShadow = (color, size) => {
  // Colors the slider to the right of the thumbpiece
  let i = 1;
  let shadow = `-${i}px 0 0 ${size} ${color}`;

  for (; i < 1950; i++) {
    //If i is a small number, like 720, then when the slider gets set to its minimum, the end of the slider is the color for the left side of the slider, when it should be the color for the right side
    shadow = `${shadow}, -${i}px 0 0 ${size} ${color}`;
  }

  return shadow;
};

const StyledSlider = styled.input`
  overflow: hidden;
  appearance: none;
  height: ${height}px;
  cursor: pointer;

  marginbottom: 0;

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: ${height}px;
    background: ${lowerBackground};
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    position: relative;
    appearance: none;
    height: ${thumb.height}px;
    width: ${thumb.width}px;
    background: url(${image});
    background-size: cover;
    border: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    box-shadow: ${makeLongShadow("blue", "-11px")};
    transition: background-color 150ms;
  }

  &::-moz-range-progress {
    background: ${lowerBackground};
  }

  &::-moz-range-track,
  &::-moz-range-progress {
    width: 100%;
    height: ${height};
    background: ${upperBackground};
  }

  &::-moz-range-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
    height: ${thumb.height}px;
    width: ${thumb.height}px;
    background: url(${image});
    border: 0;
    transition: background-color 150ms;
  }

  &::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: ${height}px;
    border: 0;
    /* color needed to hide track marks */
    color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
  }

  &::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: ${lowerBackground};
  }

  &::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: ${upperBackground};
  }

  &::-ms-thumb {
    appearance: none;
    height: ${thumb.height}px;
    width: ${thumb.height}px;
    background: url(${image});
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 0;
    transition: background-color 150ms;
    /* IE Edge thinks it can support -webkit prefixes */
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
`;

//!Black line is too thick when then margin at the bottom is 11 or 10 ? I don't know what would cause this
export default (props) => <StyledSlider type="range" {...props} />;
```

Comment: The best illegitimate solution for me was the edit the image to have the blue line, but I can't figure out how to round it still

Comment: If you have a solution that can only solve one of my problems, and there are no answers that solve both, I'll give you the bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed `box-shadow` repetition is causing slow performance, I fixed your code problems and improved the code.
In the code, I wrote comments that will help you to understand what I did.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

import "./styles.css";
const image = "https://i.imgur.com/XMfYtkv.png";

const thumbD = "50px"; // image width + height prefered same value

const filllC = "blue"; //first line
const trackC = "gray"; //second line
const trackH = "0.6em"; //dont change it if not neccessry
const firstFillthicker = 10; //in px
const secondFillthicker = 4; //in px

const track = css`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  height: ${secondFillthicker}px;
  background: ${trackC};
  border-radius: 8px;
`;

const trackFill = css`
  ${track};
  height: ${firstFillthicker}px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(${filllC}, ${filllC}),
    linear-gradient(${trackC}, ${trackC});
  background-size: var(--sx) ${firstFillthicker}px,
    calc(100% - var(--sx)) ${secondFillthicker}px;
  background-position: left center, right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
const inputCSS = css`
  width: 100%;
  --min: 0;
  --max: 100;
  --val: 50;
`;
const fill = css`
  height: ${trackH};
  background: ${filllC};
  border-radius: 4px;
`;

const thumb = css`
  margin-top: calc(0.5 * (${trackH} - ${thumbD}));
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: -15px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: transparent; // should add this for firefox
  background-image: url(${image});
  border: none;
  width: ${thumbD};
  height: ${thumbD};
`;

const StyledSlider = styled.input`
  &,
  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
  }

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
  }

  --range: calc(var(--max) - var(--min));
  --ratio: calc((var(--val) - var(--min)) / var(--range));
  --sx: calc(0.5 * ${thumbD} + var(--ratio) * (100% - ${thumbD}));

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: ${thumbD};
  background: transparent;
  font: 1em/1 arial, sans-serif;

  &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    ${trackFill};
  }

  &::-moz-range-track {
    ${track};
  }

  &::-ms-track {
    ${track};
  }

  &::-moz-range-progress {
    ${fill};
  }

  &::-ms-fill-lower {
    ${fill};
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    ${thumb};
  }

  &::-moz-range-thumb {
    ${thumb};
  }

  &::-ms-thumb {
    margin-top: 0;
    ${thumb};
  }

  &::-ms-tooltip {
    display: none;
  }

  &::-moz-focus-outer {
    border: 0;
  }
`;

export default (props) => <StyledSlider type="range" {...props} />;
```

Make sure to pass in props the `onInput` function and `style` like so

```
function Exam(){
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(50);
   return (
    <App onInput={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      style={{width: "80%","--min": 0,"--max": 100, "--val": value}} // pass the value from the props
     />
   )
}
```

Here is a live example

[image: Edit Slider (styled-components) (forked)]

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the background of the image is a light now. [It looks like this](https://imgur.com/7UTJgq6)

Comment: *is a light gray

Comment: @Sam Can you update your CodeSandBox so I can see the problem clearly?

Comment: It happens when I visit your sandbox, in Firefox

Comment: It does not happen in chrome though

Comment: @Sam I will check it soon and let you know

Comment: @Sam Actually, this because of Shadow DOM It is created by the browser to provide an encapsulation interface in HTML and it's not created in firefox by default so you need to enable it in browser settings or we should code it manually. it's too late in my time zone now, I will take a deep look at it tomorrow

Comment: At first glance, I thought it's because of Shdow DOM in firefox but actually, you just need to add `background-color: transparent;` in `const thumb = css` it's gonna fix it, LOL. Check out my sandbox

Comment: So I checked out firefox and there was [another weird problem](https://imgur.com/a/w7CXzJG) In each of those images, chrome is on top, and firefox is on the bottom

Comment: So I ran into a problem. In my program I have a spot where there two sliders whose values are inverse to eachother. With this situation the thumb on the opposite slider doesn't move, here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-styled-components-forked-3pdqr?file=/src/index.js:0-834) of this situation

Comment: @Sam https://codesandbox.io/s/slider-styled-components-forked-k10tb